# How can I include an ansible fact from the mangement side?

Tags: linux, ansible

(New to ansible) I'm running `ansible all -m setup` on a handful of hosts to produce JSON output for our inventory system. Some of our ansible remotes are in different subnets (DMZs for instance). I'd like to include the **LAN IP** associated with these hosts in the ansible JSON output. How can I do this?

UPDATE: To clarify, I would like the `192.168.1.1` ip address to be in the fact output somehow. The `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` field and `ansible_default_ipv4` in the output contains `10.10.10.1` which isn't a helpful IP address to people looking at the inventory from a LAN perspective.

```
192.168.1.0/24       192.168.1.0/24
    LAN ----------------FIREWALL
                         |     |
                         eth0  eth1
                         |     |
                         |     +-------DMZ1---------+
                         |                         |
       host1.org.net   > + eth0:1=192.168.1.1      + 10.10.10.1  > host1.org.net
                         |                         |
       host2.org.net   > + eth0:2=192.168.1.2      + 10.10.10.2  > host2.org.net
```

Comment: They should already be in those facts if they're local interfaces.... Are you looking for LOM IPs??

Comment: Right, the IP addresses are already in the facts.

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear about what I'm needing or I've completely missed something obvious. I've added a diagram and will go look through the JSON output again. Perhaps my grep was on a line break or something.

Comment: Ansible uses `ip -4 route get 8.8.8.8` to determine the default IPv4 address. This is reasonable on a properly configured host. As for your other interface, make sure you haven't configured them [ancient style with aliases](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface). If you have, switch your config to the modern method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I think ansible is working fine. The management host (where ansible is launched from) is on the LAN. I'd like to know if there's a way to include a fact from that end of the connection, not from the endpoint. The endpoint, in my case, has no way to find out what it's IP would be in the LAN DNS view.

Comment: The setup module returns information gathered from the managed system.  If you want to set additional facts or modify them, you would probably need to create a playbook.  In a playbook you should be able to go up with a way to gather facts, and then add more based on information from your inventory.  Another option might be to set custom facts on the machines.

Comment: @zoredache will a "command: " from a playbook execute on the controller, or on the remote? If I can get the host IP on the controller, then use a playbook "command" to dump the output into /etc/ansible/facts.d/lan_ip then that may work. I would just need to "get_facts" after placing the file. Is that what you had in mind? I've tried a test run simplying doing "command: ifconfig > /tmp/lan_ip" and I get an error. I need to read up more on playbooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution seems to be to run a playbook to populate a file in `/etc/ansible/facts.d/whatever.fact` using the `"{{inventory_hostname}}"` variable. When `setup` runs, it will include the `whatever.fact` in the JSON output. It's here in case it helps anyone else:
[How can I log inventory_hostname to a file on the remote using a Playbook?](https://serverfault.com/questions/901433/how-can-i-log-inventory-hostname-to-a-file-on-the-remote-using-a-playbook/901471#901471)